# Responsive background image in 100% width div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having a query with my site currently which I require some assistance with.

When a user will load up my site, the image of the 'cutlery pouch' will be resized according to how big the user's browser/monitor is. However when this happens the image some users see will be the background of the image, instead of the main feature, the pouch.

I was wondering if there was a way around this so the image resizes when using 100% width and a fixed height.

Here is a quick link to my problem so you guys may be able to help me.

[A link to my website](http://pouchmedia.co.uk/Unnamed%20Site%204/)

Thank you in advance for any helpful responses.

[image: Here is an example of what the site looks like on a colleague's square sized monitor after I followed the helpful comment of Kevin]

Comment: please post relevant code on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
background-position: 0 22%;
```

try

```
background-position: center 22%;
```

And perhaps edit the image to have the pouch more centered.

Comment: Tried that, its fine on most computers but square monitors throw up the stuff like the image I have added to my post, thanks :) @amenadiel

Comment: you still need to crop and re-center your image to match the aspect ratio you want. After all, all you need is an image with a height of 500px and a width to cover most resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just adjust your image so that the pouch is centered in the image itself, then use background-position: center;

Edit: I notice your image is a square, where as the container you're putting it in is a rectangle. This is also not helping towards it being positioned correctly. Try adjusting your image to the aspect ratio of the container as well.